# How to deploy ASP.Net web application to IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, sharepoint, publish

I am new to .Net world. I have a web application built in Visual Studio 2010 and want to publish that web application to IIS. This web application is already hosted under a SharePoint IIS website (SharePoint web site and .net web application is hosted under same IIS folder, on same port 80). I have edited my web application code and want to replace this new web application built to the existing IIS folder. Can some one please explain me in simple steps, how can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you just need to copy your updated files into your IIS folder?

Comment: Yes. For this time I need to copy and replace the existing website built. But I would also like to know how to do a new website deployment.